# Calculating relay operating times, according to IEC 60255

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, matplotlib

The script below is used to determine relay operating times, as defined in the standard IEC 60255. The equation and relevant information can be found [here](https://www.schneider-electric.com/documents/electrical-distribution/en/shared/interactive-catalogue/seped303005en/seped303005en/pdfs/page_103.pdf).

`curve_equation` takes three input values, and outputs a list of values representing the trip times for currents in the fixed range `np.logspace(np.log10(Is), 5, 1e2)`.

The part in the bottom plots the trip times for the different curves. The function `curve_equation` will be used to much more than that, so I'm mostly interested in improvements to that one.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Apr 29 13:28:26 2018

@author: Stewie
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def curve_equation(curve_name, T, Is):
    """ 
    This function calculates and returns the inverse curves for 
    the selected curve type.
    Input:
        curve_name: one of the strings: "SIT", "VIT", "LTI", "EIT", "UIT"
        T: The time dial setting. Typically in the range 0.1 ... 1
        Is: The current setting. Typically in the range 100-10000

    The appropriate k, alpha and theta values are selected based on the
    curve type.
    """

    # Define constants to be used in the curve equation    
    k = (0.14, 13.5, 120, 80, 315.2)
    alpha = (0.02, 1, 2, 2, 2.5)
    beta = (2.97, 1.5, 13.33, 0.808, 1)    
    curve_types = ("SIT", "VIT", "LTI", "EIT", "UIT")

    # idx is the index of the values we want
    try:
        idx = curve_types.index(curve_name)
    except:
        print("Non-existing curve-type")
        return

    I = np.logspace(np.log10(Is), 5, 1e2)

    def td_equation():
        td = k[idx]/((I/Is)**alpha[idx]-1) * (T / beta[idx])
        return(td)

    return(td_equation())

# For testing / plotting purposes:   
curve_types = ("SIT", "VIT", "LTI", "EIT", "UIT")
I = np.logspace(1, 5, 1e2)
for curve_type in curve_types:
    plt.loglog(I, curve_equation(curve_type, 1, 1e2), label=curve_type)

plt.xlabel("Current [A]")
plt.ylabel("Time [s]")
plt.title("IEC Time/current curves")
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: I get a `NameError: name 'I' is not defined` error on the `plt.loglog(I, …)` line.

Comment: @200_success thanks for noticing! It should work now. I made a mistake and removed that line.`I` was already stored as a variable outside the function so I didn't get an error message when I removed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need not declare `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in Python 3: [UTF-8 is the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083111/should-i-use-encoding-declaration-in-python3).

Writing `I = np.logspace(…)` inside your `curve_equation` function is bad practice, because it hard-codes certain *x*-values for your plot.  In fact, your plot is wrong, because the calculations are for \$I_s\$ values ranging from 10<sup>2</sup> A to 10<sup>5</sup> A (due to the inner `I = np.logspace(np.log10(Is), 5, 1e2)`), but your plot's *x* axis is labelled as if the values ranged from 10<sup>1</sup> A to 10<sup>5</sup> A (due to the outer `I = np.logspace(1, 5, 1e2)`).  Specifically, four of the curves should intersect at 1 kA, 10 s.

I also find the way in which the curves are specified very cumbersome.  You have five magic strings ("SIT", "VIT", etc.) which you search for in `curve_types`.  Then, you retrieve the `k`, `alpha`, and `beta` parameters by using the corresponding index.  Printing an error message and returning `None` is an inappropriate error-handling mechanism; you should raise or propagate an exception for such a fatal error.

I'd rather specify the parameters the other way: each curve should be defined as a \$(k, \alpha, \beta)\$ tuple.  To do that, I would use `namedtuple`s.  I'd go a bit further and make each `namedtuple` smart enough to know what its own \$td(I)\$ function looks like, when \$T\$ and \$I_s\$ are specified.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class IEC_Curve(namedtuple('IEC_Curve', 'name k alpha beta')):
    def td(self, T, Is):
        """
        The td(I) function for a given IEC curve, time dial setting, and
        current setting.
        """
        return lambda I: self.k * T / self.beta / ((I / Is)**self.alpha - 1)

SIT = IEC_Curve('SIT', k=0.14, alpha=0.02, beta=2.97)   # Standard inverse / A
VIT = IEC_Curve('VIT', k=13.5, alpha=1, beta=1.5)       # Very inverse / B
LTI = IEC_Curve('LTI', k=120, alpha=2, beta=13.33)      # Long time inverse / B
EIT = IEC_Curve('EIT', k=80, alpha=2, beta=0.808)       # Extremely inverse / C
UIT = IEC_Curve('UIT', k=315.2, alpha=2.5, beta=1)      # Ultra inverse

I = np.logspace(2, 5, 1e2)
for curve in (SIT, VIT, LTI, EIT, UIT):
    plt.loglog(I, curve.td(T=1, Is=1e2)(I), label=curve.name)
plt.xlabel("Current [A]")
plt.ylabel("Time [s]")
plt.title("IEC Time/current curves")
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

---

Note that `td` is a method that returns a function.  To calculate values of \$td\$ with fixed \$T\$, fixed \$I_s\$, and swept \$I\$:

```
UIT.td(T=1, Is=1e2)(I=np.logspace(2, 5, 1e2))
```

To calculate a value of \$td\$ for a given \$T\$, \$I_s\$, and \$I\$:

```
UIT.td(T=1, Is=1e2)(I=1e2)
```

(This happens to cause a `ZeroDivisionError`, which manifests itself as a `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide` at the beginning of the sweep.)

---

In case you feel intimidated by my use of inheritance of `namedtuple`, you could use a manually written constructor instead:

```
class IEC_Curve:
    def __init__(self, name, k, alpha, beta):
        self.name = name
        self.k = k
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta

    def td(self, T, Is):
        return lambda I: self.k * T / self.beta / ((I / Is)**self.alpha - 1)
```

One difference is that `namedtuple`s are immutable, whereas the members here are mutable.

Comment: Thanks! I was originally planning on using the `namedtuple` approach, but didn't know how to do it, since I've never heard of it. I only knew about `key, value` pairs, and I needed more than one value per key.

Comment: Hardcoding the `I`-values was actually intentional, since the range of the plot is usually fixed, and giving `I` as input would indicate that it's a variable, when it actually isn't. It's always from `Is` (which is already an input), and up to `10**5`. Passing both `Is` and `I` is unnecessary since `I` doesn't give any information. I agree with you though... This is better!

Comment: How do I get the operating times (the list of values) from the function, when I know the curve type? I seldom want all values (that's why I have it as an input).

Comment: @StewieGriffin Just make it a dictionary with the names as the keys and the `IEC_Curve`s as values.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining how I can use it! This is great!